# Angular2 and jQuery: How to call component level function?

Tags: jquery, angular, semantic-ui

Angular2 and jQuery combo is confusing me.  Please help!
When I invoke a popup dialog, and onApprove case, I want to call Component's level `function test()`, however, it it causing a run time error:

> ```
> "TypeError: this.test is not a function"
> ```

Any advice is appreciated!

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
declare var $: any;

    enter code here

@Component({
  selector: 'app-schedule',
  templateUrl: './schedule.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./schedule.component.less']
})

export class ScheduleComponent implements OnInit {

  scheduled : boolean;
  constructor() {
    this.scheduled = false;
   }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  test() {
    console.log('hello');
  }

  deleteConfirmDlg() {
    $('.mini.modal')
      .modal({
        closable  : false,
        onDeny    : function(){
          window.alert('Wait not yet!');
          return false;
        },
        onApprove : function() {
          this.test();
        }
      }).modal('show');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use right arrow operator to have access to `this`

```
deleteConfirmDlg() {
 $('.mini.modal')
  .modal({
    closable  : false,
    onDeny    : function(){
      window.alert('Wait not yet!');
      return false;
    },
    onApprove : () => {
      this.test();
    }
  }).modal('show');
 }
}
```

Comment: Once you get used to fat arrow functions, it's hard to ever want to use the `function () { ... }` form again. So. Much. Unnecessary. Typing. :-)

Comment: Yasss!  Thank you.  I thought the fat arrow was optional.  You made my day!

Comment: the fat arrow function notation is the one that makes it possible to refer to component variables that we access via "this"